# Is there a way to query the current brightness level of a the MacBook LCD?

Tags: macos, lcd, screen-brightness

The idea being that, once the brightness passes a certain level, one could switch to a different visual scheme to give greater visibility. Also, if it could be some sort of listener type thing, that would be even better, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

epatel was pretty close, I just had to change the AppleGraphicsControlBacklight keyword to something else to get it to work on my macbook, so I'd guess that this is something that might change between OSX versions and/or macbook versions.

I threw together a short ruby script to print out a little visual indicator on the command line.

```
# grab the string containing the values
brite_string = `ioreg -c AppleBacklightDisplay | grep brightness`

# build a regex to match those vals
brite_regex  = /"brightness"=\{"min"=([0-9]{1,3}),"value"=([0-9]{1,3}),"max"=([0-9]{1,3})/

# match them
match_data = brite_regex.match(brite_string)

# extract the values from the match
min = match_data[1].to_i
val = match_data[2].to_i
max = match_data[3].to_i

# print them out nice
puts "Current Brightness"
print "["

max.times do  |i|
  print i > val ? " " : "*"
end

puts "]"
```

Comment: Great scripting...I thought a more C/C++/ObjC solution was actually wanted. It should be possible accessing it through IOKit then...

Comment: Eventually, yeah, I might want something a little more connected to IOKit. This is basically just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 3):

I believe one could look it up with IOKit. Running the ioreg command in the terminal as below gives two lines where a brightness value is visible.

```
% ioreg -c AppleGraphicsControlBacklight | grep brightness

| | |     "IODisplayParameters" = {"brightness"={"min"=0,"value"=408,"max"=1024},"commit"={"reg"=0}}
| |   |     "IODisplayParameters" = {"brightness"={"min"=0,"value"=408,"max"=1024},"commit"={"reg"=0}}
```

Maybe someone with enough IOKit knowledge could put together a sample...

Comment: ioreg -c AppleGraphicsControlBacklight | grep brightness returns nothing. I have MAC Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

I found many tools that promised to query or set the brightness for my MacBook M2, no tool worked so far. Even the [answer from epatel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547941) didn't work for me either. The command output simply has no brightness part.
But there is an App called "[Lunar](https://lunar.fyi/#cli)" with different controls for display brightness etc.

Using that tool can have benefits, but many options are Pro features. The tool is good, but I don't really need any of their UI features. I just wanted to use the CLI to query the current brightness of my internal Mac screen or turn it on / off. The CLI is not a Pro feature.

```bash
# install CLI once (after installing the app)
/Applications/Lunar.app/Contents/MacOS/Lunar install-cli
```

Make sure to have `~/.local/bin/` in your PATH.

#### The commands to use

From their command documentation:

> OVERVIEW: Control displays or get data about the current state of the displays.
>
> EXAMPLE:
> Set brightness for monitors named Dell to 60%: `lunar displays dell brightness 60`
> Print contrast of monitors with `LG` and `4K` in their name: `lunar displays lg4k contrast`
> Rotate main display to portrait mode: `lunar displays main rotation 90`
> Print details of all displays: `lunar displays`
>
> USAGE: lunar displays [<options>] [<display>] [<property>] [<value>]

The internal screen can be controlled by the CLI as follows:

```bash
# query internal screen
lunar displays "Built-in" brightness

# Produces this output:
# 0: Built-in
#      brightness: 100

# Get the number
lunar displays "Built-in" brightness | \
  grep brightness | `# get second line` \
  awk -F':' '{ print $2 }' # Get 'argument' no. 2 (the '100')

# turn internal screen off
lunar displays "Built-in" brightness 0

# turn internal screen on
lunar displays "Built-in" brightness 100
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm not associated with the company providing this tool. I just found no other tool working on my device.
Maybe someone can benefit from this. Otherwise, the other tools out there should just be fixed by their maintainers to work as expected on systems like mine. That would be equally acceptable for me. For now, I just continue to use this CLI.

Answer (score -3):

I am not a mac guy, but does /proc exist in the filesystem?  You might want to look in that virtual file directory if it exists.

Comment: /proc doesn't exist on Max OS X. I don't know if some other directory plays the same role.

Comment: hm.. yea just taking a guess since linux and OS X are more or less cousins.

Comment: /proc does exist, but isn't mounted on the filesystem.  You can still access it programatically.  [citation-needed]